# Go through object when keys are know

Tags: javascript, loops, object, reactjs

I have object

```
var routes = {
  "home":{
    hash: "/home",
    children: {
       "just-home": {
            hash: "/home/just-home",
            children: {...}
        },
        "sub-homea": {
             hash: "/home/sub-homea",
             children: {...}
    }
  },
"contact":{
    hash: "/contact",
    children: {
       "just-contact": {
            hash: "/contact/just-contact",
            children: {...}
        },
        "sub-contact": {
             hash: "/contact/sub-contact",
             children: {...}
    }
  }
}
```

How i can set object to `just-contact.children` when i know for example - that first key is contact, and next just-contat.. ? I need to assign this object dynamically because the known keys will be all time different. So i need use any loop. something like this  -

```
const pathArray = [contact,just-contact]
Object.keys(routes).map(function (item) {
              if (routes[item] === pathArray[counter]){
                  ob = routes[item];
                  counter++;
              }
            })
```

but this will loop only once and it won't go to deep.

**UPDATE**  for more clean explanation -
I will read from path location (localhost:3000/contact/just-contact) the values (contact,just-contact) , which i will save to array (`pathArray=[contact,just-contact]`), when the location path will be change, the keys in array will be change too. And i need to find children of last key, in this example children of  `just-contact` key

Comment: The question is unclear. You say that the keys are known *("I know that first key is contact...")*, but you also say the keys are not known *("the known keys will all time different"*). Which is it? A [mcve] would help.

Comment: Please try to explain the problem better, it's very difficult to correct your answer.

Comment: What is difficult? I just need to find object inside object, when i know keys.(path)

Comment: No, "known" was correct. What's not correct is that you've said in one place the keys are known, and in another place that they'll be different all the time. Which is it? Will they be known, so we can hardcode them, or different from run to run, so we have to discover them at runtime?

Comment: I want to say, that the keys will be known all time ( keys will be save in array ). But they can be different all time.

Comment: I will read from path location (http://localhost:3000/contact/just-contact) the keys (contact,just-contact) , which i will save to array (`pathArray=[contact,just-contact]`), when the location path will be change, its sure, that the keys in array will be change too. I dont know how i can say it differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found simple solution -

```
pathArray.map(function (item) {
      if (obj[item].hash === item){
             obj = obj[item].children;
      }
})
```